# What Happens to custom Counters if Mappers fails in Midway and Hadoop re-tries that mapper

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I have a mapper which reads data from DB and updates the counters with 'number of read' counters and 'processed records' counters. If the mappers fails in between may due to not getting enough resources to run then what happens to the counters?  Are the reset?
      In my case the data is very huge around 40 million records. It took 3 days and  92 retires to complete but during the running of job, the counters were good but when it terminated the values of counters were halved, could not understand please help.

Answer (score 2):

Each task counters (either for mapper or reducer) are related to task attempt, so when task attempt fails (due to a bug / IO problems) or killed (speculative execution) related counters are dropped.